# sendmail & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, nginx

I had MySQL and PHP working good in the nginx server. For mailing purpose I installed sendmail.

Now all I get is `Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.` in my WordPress site [here](http://nz.proitzen.com/nickies/)

Now no idea how to make it work again. I've restarted MySQL, nginx but nothing helped so far. Can someone enlighten me please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to restart php5-fpm to get it work.

Also to fix the email problem, what I did was removed `sendmail` and stopped the process running at port 25 and installed `postfix` internet mail.

Everything started to work like charm afterwards.